# Should I pluralize "University" in the phrase "Yale and Harvard Universities"?

Tags: grammatical-number, capitalization, proper-nouns

I'm wondering if I need to pluralize "University" in the following sentence:

"Our expert panelists, including former admissions officers from Yale and Harvard Universities, will discuss..."

Should it be plural and capitalized? Singular? Lower case?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Why do you think the plural may not be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"University" should be capitalized with Yale because it's the official name: "Yale University" (per the [footer in their website](https://www.yale.edu/)).

"University" doesn't need to be capitalized with Harvard, because the official name is "Harvard College" (per the [footer in their website](https://www.harvard.edu/)). Although they do use the term "Harvard University" throughout their site.

In plural form, "Yale and Harvard universities" is fine. I can't imagine anybody seeing a legitimate fault in that formulation.

Also, if it's already clear from previous sentences or paragraphs that you're talking about higher education, then "universities" may not be needed at all. Consider simply:

> *"Our expert panelists, including former admissions officers from Yale
>   and Harvard, will discuss..."*

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of just dropping "universities" - I'll go with that!

Comment: From the Universities of Yale and Harvard